# Get specific string line from file bash

Tags: json, bash, sed, grep, jq

I have a file with this kind of text with pattern

```
[{"foo":"bar:baz:foo*","bar*":"baz*","etc":"etc"},
{"foo2":"bar2:baz2:foo2*","bar2*":"baz2*","etc":"etc"},
{"foo3":"bar3:baz3:foo3*","bar3*":"baz3*","etc":"etc"},
{"foo4":"bar4:baz4:foo4*","bar4*":"baz4*","etc":"etc"}]
```

I  need to take every string like this
`{"foo":"bar:baz:foo*","bar*":"baz*","etc":"etc"}` and send each of them to some url via curl

```
for i in text.txt
do (awk,sed,grep etc)
then curl $string
```

I can't figure out how to get the desired lines properly from the file without unnecessary symbols

Comment: the jsons are not valid json

Comment: @bigbounty a typo, sorry

Comment: If you deal with real [JSON](http://json.org/) content, you'll find *many* open source libraries and programs to handle it. But JSON should be mentioned in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you can use `jq` to process your json file.  `jq` is capable of reading json, and formatting output.  Here's an example `jq` script to process your json file (which I unimaginatively call 'jsonfile'):

```
jq -r '.[] | "curl -d '\'' \(.) '\''  http://restful.com/api " ' jsonfile
```

Here's the output:

```
curl -d ' {"foo":"bar:baz:foo*","bar*":"baz*","etc":"etc"} '  http://restful.com/api 
curl -d ' {"foo2":"bar2:baz2:foo2*","bar2*":"baz2*","etc":"etc"} '  http://restful.com/api 
curl -d ' {"foo3":"bar3:baz3:foo3*","bar3*":"baz3*","etc":"etc"} '  http://restful.com/api 
curl -d ' {"foo4":"bar4:baz4:foo4*","bar4*":"baz4*","etc":"etc"} '  http://restful.com/api
```

Here's what's going on:

We pass three arguments to the `jq` program:  jq -r <script> <inputfile>.
The `-r` tells jq to output the results in raw format (that is, please don't escape quotes and stuff).
The script looks like this:

```
.[] | "some string \(.)"
```

The first `.` means take the whole json structure and the `[]` means iterate through each array element in the structure.  The `|` is a filter that processes each element in the array.  The filter is to output a string. We are using `\(.)` to interpolate the whole element passed into the `|` filter.

Wow... I've never really explained a `jq` script before (and it shows).  But the crux of it is, we are using jq to find each element in the json array and insert it into a string.  Our string is this:

```
curl -d '<the json dictionary array element>' http://restful.com/api
```

Ok.  And you see the output.  It works.  But wait a second, we only have output.  Let's tell the shell to run each line like this:

```
jq -r '.[] | "curl -d '\'' \(.) '\''  http://restful.com/api " ' jsonfile | bash
```

By piping the output to bash, we execute each line that we output.  Essentially, we are writing a bash script with jq to curl http://restful.com/api passing the json element as the `-d` data parameter to POST the json element.

### Revisiting for single quote issue

@oguz ismail pointed out that bash will explode if there is a single quote in the json input file.  This is  true.   We can avoid the quote by escaping, but we gain more complexity - making this a non-ideal approach.

Here's the problem input (I just inserted a single quote):

```
[{"foo":"bar:'baz:foo*","bar*":"baz*","etc":"etc"},
{"foo2":"bar2:baz2:foo2*","bar2*":"baz2*","etc":"etc"},
{"foo3":"bar3:baz3:foo3*","bar3*":"baz3*","etc":"etc"},
{"foo4":"bar4:baz4:foo4*","bar4*":"baz4*","etc":"etc"}]
```

Notice above that `baz` is now `'baz`.  The problem is that a single single quote makes the bash shell complain about unmatched quotes:

```
$ jq -r '.[] | "curl -d '\'' \(.) '\''  http://restful.com/api " ' jsonfile | bash
bash: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Here's the solution:

```
$ jq -r  $'.[] |    "\(.)"  | gsub( "\'" ; "\\\\\'" )  | "echo $\'\(.)\'" ' jsonfile     | bash
{"foo":"bar'baz:foo*","bar*":"baz*","etc":"etc"}
{"foo2":"bar2:baz2:foo2*","bar2*":"baz2*","etc":"etc"}
{"foo3":"bar3:baz3:foo3*","bar3*":"baz3*","etc":"etc"}
{"foo4":"bar4:baz4:foo4*","bar4*":"baz4*","etc":"etc"}
```

Above I am using $'' to quote the jq script.  This allows me to escape single quotes using '.   I've also changed the `curl` command to `echo` so I can test the bash script without bothering the folks at `http://restful.com/api`.

The 'trick' is to make sure that the bash script we generate also escapes all single quotes with a backslash .  So, we have to change `'` to `\'`.  That's what gsub is doing.

```
gsub( "\'" ; "\\\\\'" )
```

After making that substitution ( `'` --> `\'` ) we pipe the entire string to this:

```
"echo $\'\(.)\'"
```

which surrounds the output of gsub with `echo $''`.  Now we are using $' again so the `\'` is properly understood by bash.

So we wind up with this when we put the curl back in:

```
jq -r  $'.[] |    "\(.)"  | gsub( "\'" ; "\\\\\'" )  | "curl -d $\'\(.)\' http://restful.com/api " ' jsonfile     | bash
```

Comment: A single quote in the JSON value and bash gets stuck. Hence the downvote.

Comment: Addressed @oguzismail single quote using gsub() to escape single quotes that might be in the jsonfile input.  Answer is too complicated now indicating this is not a good approach, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jq` command. This is just example parsing.

```
for k in $(jq -c '.[]' a.txt); do
    echo "hello-" $k
done
```

Output:

```
hello- {"foo":"bar:baz:foo*","bar*":"baz*","etc":"etc"}
hello- {"foo2":"bar2:baz2:foo2*","bar2*":"baz2*","etc":"etc"}
hello- {"foo3":"bar3:baz3:foo3*","bar3*":"baz3*","etc":"etc"}
hello- {"foo4":"bar4:baz4:foo4*","bar4*":"baz4*","etc":"etc"}
```

You can use the `$k` anywhere inside the loop you want.

```
for k in $(jq -c '.[]' a.txt); do
    curl -d "$k" <url>
done
```

Comment: I've never seen the `-c` option of jq used before.  I've got to say that I like it.  The use of $() may result in the json object being chopped up, though.  Consider the case where baz is really just a space.  Any spaces in the quoted string might be trouble.  I think you might be able to get around that with IFS="\n" (not sure).  And you may need to put double quotes around $k as well: `-d "$k"`

Comment: `-c = compact instead of pretty-printed output;`. Added within double quotes

Comment: Yeah, `while read -r json; do curl ... ; done < "$(jq ...)"` would be a better approach.